# Mosfet power dissipation in this example

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, fet, power-dissipation

I am trying to design a buck regulator with the following specification:
Vin = 24V
Vout = 5V
I max = 8A
Fsw=300k. The load is basically a long strip of RGB LED's. Which in certain cases would be all white for certain durations. I

I don't have many options for FET selection (chip shortages) so i went with NP20P04SLG (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/np20p04slg-data-sheet)

And the buck regulator is LM25085A (https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm25085a.pdf?ts=1635166406663&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM25085A)

Here is a snippet of the schematic (note the FET is not as shown here but the one i've just mentioned above) :
[image]

I am trying to calculate how hot my FET will get.

I appreciate there is a combination of continuous losses and the switching losses on turn on and turn off for the FET.

I found the following eqn for swithcing losses here (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt664/slyt664.pdf?ts=1635224006712&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F):
[image]

Which if i try to calculate (i think) is 24 * 8 * 300k *((4n + 8n)/1.75A) = **0.39W**
For starters i took the 1.75A from the LM25085 datasheet where it was IPgate. Is that right?

The continuous conduction loss is given as :
[image]

The datasheet for LM25085A suggests a good estimation for ripple as 20% of max load current so = 1.6A
Rdson = 25mohms
This gives me  25m * (5/24) * (8^2 + (1.6^2/12)) = **0.334W**

This gives a total dissipation of 0.334 + 0.39 = 0.724W.

So the max temp would be: 125 * 0.724 = 90.5 degrees.

Is this a correct work through of the FET temperature? Since i can't use parts found commonly on places like webbench (shortages) i want to make sure these parts would also work just fine.

On a side note what are the two power dissipation values in this datasheet below for this FET (38W and 1.2W)?

[image]

Comment: Kudos for asking a clear question with all info needed! *For starters i took the 1.75A from the LM25085 datasheet where it was IPgate. Is that right?* That 1.75 A is the **source** current (going to the gate), the **sink** current is somewhat lower at 1.5 A. I would take the avreage of those two so 1.625 A then you'll get slightly more dissipation. However, this is specified at Vin = 12 V and you're using Vin = 24 V and that might give you a slight advantage. But all-in-all I'd say that your 0.39 W is **close enough**.

Comment: *So the max temp would be: 125 * 0.724 = 90.5 degrees.* That's not correct, the temperature **increase** would be 90.5 C. You will need to start from the ambient temperature. For example: Tamb = 50 C then with 90.5 C increase you would get 140.5 C. Which is far too hot! Luckily that 125 K/W applies when you mount the MOSFET in "free air" which is not how it should be used. You need to mount it on a **heatsink**. That can be a separate (aluminium or copper)) heatsink, the metal case of your product or a large copper area on the PCB.

Comment: Note how the Thermal resistance to the case is much lower at 3.9 K/W so if your heatsink's thermal resistance is low enough then dissipating that 0.7 W will not be an issue.

Comment: *On a side note what are the two power dissipation values in this datasheet below for this FET (38W and 1.2W)?* The 38 W is when you keep Tc (case temperature) at 25 C, that means a proper heatsink is used! The 1.2 W is in an ambient (air) temperature of 25 C and no heatsink, then only 1.2 W is enough to almost overheat the MOSFET. This shows the importance of a good heatsink.

Comment: More than looking at the thermal limit of the mosfet it's more sensible to compute the actual temperature you reach with the power you are dissipating. I found that in practice that value is a little on the optimistic side